Where does the energy go if a fully loaded lithium battery in an electric vehicle cools down?
If the battery of an electric vehicle was charged to 100% at room temperature the ev has about 100% reach. Now assume the battery is colder and therefore reach drops. What happend to the original battery energy charged? If the battery has room temperature again the reach is 100% again?
If the battery is charged at a lower temperature with energy Eload and then used at room temperature: Is there a larger energy E > Eload now available from the battery?

I'll add this article on research performed by the Idaho National Laboratory and released in 2020 to the topic, since it introduces the fact that your question requires careful clarification of conditions before attempting an answer.

A Li-Ion battery basically can supply the same charge at any temperature. However the (internal) losses from resistance generally are higher at colder temperatures; thus at a given current, the voltage is lower.
There is also a small effect on the no-load voltage.
So, when consuming current at different temperatures, consider that the cell still generates the same power, but it doesn't all reach the terminals because of higher internal resistance at cold. Ultimately, the 'lost' energy is dissipated inside the cell (and heats it up which improves the delivery...).
Analogously, when you charge at colder temperatures, you have to supply a higher voltage to 'force' the charge into the cell -- this 'wasted' energy just heats up the cell.
The no-load voltage changes (and consequential small changes in energy delivered) are reflected in the thermal capacitance (specific heat) of the cell.

Could you say that there is an optimal temperature at which the battery operates and, depending on ambient temperature, part of the energy is naturally used to reach this temperature? obviously only true as long as the ambient temperature is lower then the optimal one, as resistance can only generate heat.

"the same charge" part is true only for relatively low discharge currents, generally C/10 or less that are not typical for EVs. At higher drain rates, the available charge pretty much depends on the temperature. The good part is, the "missing" charge is still in the battery and can be recovered if the battery is warmed, or used at lower discharge rates.

@fraxinus, I assume the same applies to low charging currents as there is also less dissipation in the resistance. So it would be better to charge at low currents when it's cold?

@monok pretty much yes, lower charging rate is always better for a battery and even more in extreme conditions. On the other hand, a lot ot car charging systems can heat up the battery in order to improve charging.
